# CodeIgniter, pass data from model to controller to use in view

Tags: php, codeigniter, scope, variable-assignment

I want to pass data queried in my model to the controller, to do so I am using return $data. Then in the controller I use `$this->load->view('my_view', $data);`

From my understanding `var_dump($data);` in the view should show me the results from the query... This is not the case. I am getting "undefined variable data" and NULL from the `var_dump($data);`.

Here is my model:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Manage_accounts_model extends CI_Model {


    public function index() {

        //

    }

    public function get_users(){

        $data = array();

        $data['query'] = $this->db->get('users');

        return $data['query'];

     }

}
```

Here is my controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Manage_accounts extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {

        $this->load->view('template/header');

        $this->load->model('manage_accounts_model');

        $this->load->view('template/footer');

        $this->load->model('manage_accounts_model');

        $res = $this->manage_accounts_model->get_users();

        if($res){

            $this->load->view('manage_accounts_view', $data);

        } else {

            echo "Fail";

        }

  }

}
```

And finally my view:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>
<div class="container">

    <h1><?php if($title){ echo $title; } ?></h1>

    <?php var_dump($data['query']); ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you made 2 mistakes

1. forget to fetch the result to an array
2. forget to pass the data to view

change in your model class.

```
public function get_users(){

    $data = array();
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    $res   = $query->result();        
    return $res;

 }
```

change in your controller class

```
public function index() {

    $this->load->view('template/header');

    $this->load->model('manage_accounts_model');

    $this->load->view('template/footer');

    $this->load->model('manage_accounts_model');

    $res = $this->manage_accounts_model->get_users();

    if($res){
        $data['result'] = $res;
        $this->load->view('manage_accounts_view', $data);

    } else {

        echo "Fail";

    }
```

in your view

```
  print_r($result);
```

Comment: $data['result'] = $res;
        $this->load->view('manage_accounts_view', $data);                                                                     so $result can be accessible in view.          $data is an associative array and its key can be used as a variable in view. sorry if iam wrong.

Comment: `$result` holds the array elements and using `echo` for array only print `Array()`, This is what i mean only. You should use `print_r($result)` or `var_dump($result)` to highlight the result.

Answer (score 1):

cause `$data` is not defined in your controller  try

```
$data = array();
if($res){
  $data['res'] = $res;
  $this->load->view('manage_accounts_view', $data);
}
```

Then get on view

```
<?php var_dump($res); ?>
```

Also you are sending whole query from model not result for return result you need like :-

```
public function get_users(){
 $query = $this->db->get('users');
 return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot it

```
 $data['resultSet']=$res;
```

Now access the result as $res in your code

Answer (score 0):

You did not pass the `query` key variable to view.

change:

```
$res = $this->manage_accounts_model->get_users();
if($res) {
  $this->load->view('manage_accounts_view', $data);
```

To:

```
$data['query'] = $this->manage_accounts_model->get_users();
if($data['query']){
  $this->load->view('manage_accounts_view', $data);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Need to do change into controller

```
$data['query'] = $this->manage_accounts_model->get_users();

if($data){
     $this->load->view('manage_accounts_view', $data);
}else{
     echo "Fail";
}
```